# Indent Error when there appears to be none

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, neural-network

You I have been trying to run this script but I keep getting an indentation error at the end
of the backprop(x,y) function. I would really appreciate ANY help!!

```
import cPickle
import gzip

def load_data():

    f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

import numpy as np

class Network(object):
    def __init__(self, layers):
        self.layers = layers
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y,1) for y
                        in layers[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.transpose(np.random.randn(x,y))
                        for x,y
                        in zip(layers[:-1],layers[1:])]
        self.num_layers = len(layers)




    def backprop(self, x, y):
        nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        # feedforward
        activation = x
        activations = [x] # list to store all the activations, layer by layer
        zs = [] # list to store all the z vectors, layer by layer
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            z = np.dot(w, activation)+b
            zs.append(z)
            activation = sigmoid(z)
            activations.append(activation)
        # backward pass
        delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
            sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])#set first delta 
        nabla_b[-1] = delta#set last dC/db to delta vector 
        nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())
        #calculate nabla_b, nabla_w for the rest of the layers
        for l in xrange(2, self.num_layers):
            z = zs[-l]
            sp = sigmoid_prime(z)   
            delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l+1].transpose(), delta) * sp
            nabla_b[-l] = delta
            nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l-1].transpose())
        #this is where python says there is an indent error!
        return (nabla_b, nabla_w)
```

Comment: I have selected all your code and pressed the `{}` button in the editor. This formats the selected text as code. Please review the question to make sure it looks like your original code. You can always [edit] your question to fix it or improve it.

Comment: Try to replace `tab` by `spaces`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  thanks for helping me format the code; I was having a bit of trouble with that... But I posted it anyway lol. Thanks again buddy!

Comment: @HaBom That fixed the problem! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by selecting the "edit" drop-down menu of Notepad++, choosing Blank Operations, and finally, clicking 'TAB to spaces'; obviously, this should be done after selecting the portion of code that's triggering the error.